# What's wrong with that mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
IF SELECT 1 FROM flevelData WHERE flevelData.Uid = 0 THEN 
    UPDATE flevelData 
        SET 'Experience' = 10,'Level' = 1
        WHERE flevelData.Uid =0;
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO flevelData ('id', 'Uid', 'Experience', 'Level') VALUES (NULL, '0', '10', '1');

END IF
```

I get the error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF SELECT 1 FROM flevelData WHERE flevelData.Uid = 0 THEN 
>       UPDATE flevelDat' at line 1

I don't understand what is wrong with the query. Could someone hint me?

Comment: Why did you single quote your column names in Update query? remove them, and I think you are good to go.

Comment: See  INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

You can use flow functions only in procedures or triggers and so on. In MySQL you can only execute a single query without a function around it.

That is the first error in your code. After that there are also several syntax issues. Use a SQL tool like *MySQL Workbench* to look at your code. You get specific error messages and can fix it.

Comment: So how do I add a function around it?

Comment: By looking up *Stored Procedure* in MySQL.